# How to put inner image inside gridview images?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-imageview

I listed all images inside a grid view in my application.What i need is that i need to add a particular inner image inside all the images.Can anyone please help me.....I am beginner to Android.The code is listed below

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected Cursor mCursor;
    protected int columnIndex;
    protected GridView mGridView;
    protected ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_gallery);

        // Get all the images on phone

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
        };

        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
        );

        columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);

     // Get the GridView layout
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Convert DP to PX

        public int dpToPx(int dps) {
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);

            return pixels;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            int imageID = 0;

            // Want the width/height of the items
            // to be 120dp
            int wPixel = dpToPx(120);
            int hPixel = dpToPx(120);

            // Move cursor to current position
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            imageID = mCursor.getInt(columnIndex);

            if (convertView == null) {
                // If convertView is null then inflate the appropriate layout file
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.conversation_item, null);
            }
            else {

            }

            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            // Set height and width constraints for the image view
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPixel, hPixel));

            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            imageView.setImageURI(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID)
            );

            // Image should be cropped towards the center
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            // Set Padding for images
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            // Crop the image to fit within its padding
            imageView.setCropToPadding(true);

            return convertView;
        }


    }


}
```

activity_photo_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

conversation_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to add inner image (any innerimage is neccecary but it should be unique for all the grid view images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another layout(with innerimage) inside the parent layout and adjust the size in xml itself.That worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewInner" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

add another image view in conversation_item.xml and handle it from Adapter